# iOS: app never run on foreground. How do I debug this problem?

Tags: ios, xcode

Environment:

macOS Catalina 10.15.4
xcode 11.5
iphone iOS 13.5.1

Hello expert, I'm a beginner developer for iOS app development.

I'm developing my iOS app and now testing it on iPhone and iPad.
It works most of the time. So I'm now actually using the app in my ordinarily
life(meaning detaching from xcode).

However, sometimes the app falls into a problematic state.
Occurrence of this problem is once per 2-3 days.

In this state, when I tried to switch the app from background to foreground,
the app behaves looks like crushing, and never run on the foreground.

But, actually the app is not crushed, because I can see the app on the background.
Once the app is in this state, the app never run on the foreground even if
I killed the process and launch the app again.
Since the app is not crushed, I can not see any crush log in my iphone.

Only way to recover this problem is to copy the app from Xcode to the iphone
and launch again.

So here is the questions.

1. Is there any way to reattach the process running on iOS to the xcode to debug again after disconnecting from xcode on my MAC ?
2. How should we debug this kinds of problem ?
   Any comments/suggestions/advices are highly appreciated.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the app crashes it will still be visible in the app switcher since that is just showing a snapshot of your app. But answering your first question you can reattach by plugging your phone and in Xcode going to `Debug > Attach to process by PID or Name...` there you can enter the name of the target you're debugging, click `Attach` and as soon as you launch the app in your phone Xcode should begin a debugging session allowing you to better debug this crash.